# After zooming in, the slightest movement of the mouse moves the display by a mile, how do I correct this?

Tags: interface

I have unwittingly changed a setting in Blender and I now need to change it back.

I have no idea what the change was, so cannot backtrack.

When I select an object and use the number pad to view it from a specific angle, it zooms right out. I zoom back in using the scroll wheel and it zooms in by a very large increment each time, and when I move the mouse even slightly the display moves by an even larger amount.

I can be centered on an object and it fills my screen, I try to move slightly to the left by nudging the mouse, and it moves so much that the object is now a tiny dot in the distance.

I'm trying to model something at 1:1 which is about 20cmx20cm.